# springboot logback: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.logback.v1.x.TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I use springboot (version: 2.1.5.RELEASE) create project, then use logback-spring.xml to record log .

the configration like this:

```
    <appender name="FILE_ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/${appName}/${appName}-error.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/${appName}/${appName}-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.logback.v1.x.TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout">
                <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>error</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
```

but when I start my  application, logback shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Could not create component [layout] of type [org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.logback.v1.x.TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.logback.v1.x.TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@20:26 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][layout][pattern]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Could not create component [layout] of type [org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.logback.v1.x.TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.skywalking.apm.toolkit.log.logback.v1.x.TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout
```

Lost some action (or how to add them) for logback?

Comment: This is probably because your application is doesn't have the skywalking plugin listed as a dependency. Add it to your projects build file (Maven, Gradle, Ivy) and rerun the project. https://github.com/apache/skywalking/blob/master/docs/en/setup/service-agent/java-agent/Application-toolkit-logback-1.x.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `TraceIdPatternLogbackLayout` from `apm-toolkit-logback-1.x` you have to dependency the toolkit

maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.skywalking</groupId>
    <artifactId>apm-toolkit-logback-1.x</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.skywalking', name: 'apm-toolkit-logback-1.x', version: '8.1.0'
```